Callback in python ctypes
I'm trying to wrap a C library in Python using ctypes. A function call requires a callback function which I implemented using the programming manual.The problem is that I'm unable get the return value as "True" from this wrapper and I'm new to callback function.
from ctypes import *

class Set_trigg(Structure):
    _fields_ = [('dev_index', c_byte),
                ('type', c_ulong)
                ]

class USB2ish(object):
    def __init__(self):
        try:
            usbio_dll = cdll.LoadLibrary("C:\\Users\\...\\usb2uis.dll")
        except:
            print("dll file not loaded, 'USB-TO-UIS driver was not present/installed'.")

    def exception_handler(self, exception):
        print("Exception occured:", exception)


    def USBIO_OpenDevice(self):
        try:
            result = cdll.usb2uis.USBIO_OpenDevice()
            print('USBIO device Successfully opened with number', result)
            return result
        except Exception as ex:
            self.exception_handler(self, ex)

    def USBIO_SetTrigNotify(self, dev_no, result):
        """ The trigger event of USB2UIS device, pTrig_CallBack will be called.
        """

        # Define the callback function type
        USB_DLL_CALLBACK = CFUNCTYPE(c_bool, POINTER(Set_trigg))

        cl_back = USB_DLL_CALLBACK(self.process)
        set_trig = Set_trigg(dev_no, 170)   # "0x00AA" = 170
        print(set_trig)

    def process(self, dev_no, result):
        print(dev_no.contents.dev_index)
        print(result.contents.type)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    rs = USB2ish()
    result = rs.USBIO_OpenDevice()
    call_back = rs.USBIO_SetTrigNotify(0, result)


Programming manual
How do I use callback method in ctypes?

Not sure if the only one, but [SO]: C function called from Python via ctypes returns incorrect value (@CristiFati's answer) could definitely be part of the problem. Also you are calling the callback manually (which doesn't seem right). Actually what is Set_trigg?

Set_trigg is nothing but a class.
class Set_trigg(Structure):
fields = [('dev_index', c_byte),
('type', c_ulong)
]

Three problems:
First, this declaration:
USB_DLL_CALLBACK = CFUNCTYPE(c_bool, POINTER(Set_trigg))

Per the programming manual, the signature of the callback must be bool function(BYTE, DWORD).
Second, I don't see where you call USBIO_SetTrigNotify in the DLL.
Third, you're passing dev_no and result as parameters to the method USBIO_SetTrigNotify, but those will be parameters that USBIO will pass to your callback.
Putting all together (untested, as I don't have the DLL):
from ctypes import wintypes
from ctypes import *

class USB2ish(object):
    def __init__(self):
        try:
            usbio_dll = cdll.LoadLibrary("C:\\Users\\...\\usb2uis.dll")
        except:
            print("dll file not loaded, 'USB-TO-UIS driver was not present/installed'.")

    def exception_handler(self, exception):
        print("Exception occured:", exception)


    def USBIO_OpenDevice(self):
        try:
            result = cdll.usb2uis.USBIO_OpenDevice()
            print('USBIO device Successfully opened with number', result)
            return result
        except Exception as ex:
            self.exception_handler(self, ex)

    def USBIO_SetTrigNotify(self):
        callback = CFUNCTYPE(c_bool, BYTE, DWORD)(self.process)
        return cdll.usb2uis.USBIO_SetTrigNOtify(callback)

    def process(self, i_dev_index, i_type):
        print(f'{i_dev_index=}')
        print(f'{i_type=}')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    rs = USB2ish()
    result = rs.USBIO_OpenDevice()
    rs.USBIO_SetTrigNotify()



I reused the above code and that returns "OSError: exception: access violation writing 0x00007FF85524BA20". is this exception because of the statement that we are pssing into CFUNCTYPE?

Could be. Can you try WINFUNCTYPE instead of CFUNCTYPE?

Modified as this method <WINFUNCTYPE(wintypes.BOOL, wintypes.BYTE, wintypes.DWORD)(self.process)>. Same error is repeating.
